# Destructor's functionalities

Tags: c++, destructor

For a simple class like this:

```
class X {
public:
//...
private:
int *ptr;
};

X::~X() {
delete ptr;
}
```

I have written a destructor to free the memory pointed to by `ptr`. Now, I am wondering, if my destructor stays like this, when is `ptr` actually destroyed?

Thanks

Comment: When the destructor is called, in first place?

Comment: it's destroyed when the `X` instance that contains `ptr` is destroyed itself.

Comment: @H2CO3 ..so it's done implicitly?

Comment: @Iceman *What* is done implicitly?

Comment: @H2CO3: the destruction of ptr

Comment: @Iceman No, you have to do that explicitly -- just like you did in your example.

Comment: @H2CO3: I mean the int * itself, not the memory it points to..

Comment: @Iceman it is destroyed when the object it is a member of is itself destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete` invokes the destructor of the object that is being deleted and then frees the memory it occupied.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this article](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr380.htm) might answer most of your questions

> "Destructors are implicitly called when an automatic object (a local
>   object that has been declared auto or register, or not declared as
>   static or extern) or temporary object passes out of scope. They are
>   implicitly called at program termination for constructed external and
>   static objects. Destructors are invoked when you use the delete
>   operator for objects created with the new operator."

More specifically:

> "The destructors of base classes and members are called in the reverse
>   order of the completion of their constructor:
>
> The destructor for a class object is called before destructors for
>   members and bases are called.
>
> Destructors for nonstatic members are called before destructors for
>   base classes are called.
>
> Destructors for nonvirtual base classes are called before destructors
>   for virtual base classes are called."

Answer (score 1):

The destructor will calls in the end of scope where the specific instance are.

Comment: This is incomplete. Destructors are also invoked when `delete` is used.

Comment: `delete` of dynamic instance? it's kind of 'end of scope'... tnx for your correction!

Answer (score 0):

The local version of ptr for a given instance of X will be destroyed when the object goes out of scope.  For example:

```
int main()
{
    X obj;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        X tmp;

        // do work with tmp
        ...

        // tmp goes out of scope here
        // the destructor tmp::~X will be called here, immediately after each iteration ends
    }

    // obj goes out of scope here
    // the destructor obj::~X called when the program ends
}
```